# how to scan a LAN for live hosts using PHP and SNMP?

Tags: php, ip, snmp, router

I would like to have a quick script listing all active hosts in a LAN, and I am a bit lost. From other posts I figured that this can be done most effectively by polling the DHCP server (in my case a Lancom router) using SNMP.

However, I am not familiar with the SNMP commands in PHP. Is snmpwalk() the correct function? Can I get snmpwalk() or any other php function to return an array that contains a list of all live hosts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I wrote a script that probes the Lancom router and pulls out the DHCP/BOOTP table. It may be used for all those who need to monitor such routers, and therefore I am sharing it. It also outputs a nice HTML table; the function `BetterTable()` can be used on any 2D array.

You will need to set IP, userid, and pwd (first three variables) in order to use the script on your router.

```
    <?php

    $router_ip = '';
    $username = '';
    $password = '';
    $port = 23;
    $timeout = 10;

    $connection = fsockopen($router_ip, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);

    if(!$connection){
     echo "Connection failed\n";
     exit();
    } else {

     fputs($connection, "$username\r\n");
     fputs($connection, "$password\r\n");
     fputs($connection, "cd setup/dhcp/dhcp-table \r\n");
     fputs($connection, "dir \r\n");
     fputs($connection, " ");

     $j = 0;
     while ($j < 16) {
      fgets($connection);
      $j++;
     }
     stream_set_timeout($connection, 2);
     $timeoutCount = 0;
     $content ='';
     $DhcpArray = '';
     (int) $index =0;

    $DhcpFile = "C:\IP-Symcon\webfront\user\images\LancomDhcp.txt";
    $fh = fopen($DhcpFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");

    //$DhcpArray[0] = array ('IP-Address', 'MAC-Address', 'Timeout', 'Hostname', 'Type', 'LAN-Ifc', 'Ethernet-Port', 'VLAN-ID', 'Network-Name');

     while (!feof($connection)){

      $content = fgets($connection);
      $content = str_replace("\r", '', $content);
      $content = str_replace("\n", "", $content);
      $lineArray = explode(' ', $content); 
      if (isValidIp($lineArray [0]))
          { 
          $DhcpArray[$index]['IP-Address'] = substr ($content, 0,17);
          $DhcpArray[$index]['MAC-Address'] = substr ($content, 17,32-18);
          $DhcpArray[$index]['Timeout'] = substr ($content, 31,41-32);
          $DhcpArray[$index]['Hostname'] = substr ($content, 40,108-41);
          $DhcpArray[$index]['Type'] = substr ($content, 107,125-108);
          $DhcpArray[$index]['LAN-Ifc'] = substr ($content, 124,137-125);
          $DhcpArray[$index]['Ethernet-Port'] = substr ($content, 136,152-137);
          $DhcpArray[$index]['VLAN-ID'] = substr ($content, 151,161-152);
          $DhcpArray[$index]['Network-Name'] = substr ($content, 160);
          fwrite($fh, $content);
          $index +=1;
          }

      # If the router say "press space for more", send space char:
      if (preg_match('/MORE/', $content) ){ // IF current line contain --More-- expression,
       fputs ($connection, " "); // sending space char for next part of output.
      } # The "more" controlling part complated.

      $info = stream_get_meta_data($connection);
      if ($info['timed_out']) { // If timeout of connection info has got a value, the router not returning a output.
       $timeoutCount++; // We want to count, how many times repeating.
      }
      if ($timeoutCount >2){ // If repeating more than 2 times,
       break;   // the connection terminating..
      }
     }
     $content = substr($content,410);

     BetterTable($DhcpArray);




    fclose($fh);

    }
    echo "End.\r\n";

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------

    function isValidIp($ip)
    {/* PCRE Pattern written by Junaid Atari */
        return !preg_match ( '/^([1-9]\d|1\d{0,2}|2[0-5]{2})\.('.
                             '(0|1?\d{0,2}|2[0-5]{2})\.){2}(0|1?'.
                             '\d{0,2}|2[0-5]{2})(\:\d{2,4})?$/',
                             (string) $ip )
                ? false
                : true;
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------

    function BetterTable($twoDimArray)
    {
    $i = 0;
    echo "<table>
            <table class='BetterTable' border='1'>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>Line #
    </td>';
    foreach ($twoDimArray[0] as  $fieldName => $fieldValue)
        {
            echo '<td>'.$fieldName. '</td>';
        }echo '</tr>';
    $i = 0;

    foreach ($twoDimArray as $rowName => $rowValue) 
    {
            if ($i%2 == 0) 
                Echo "<tr bgcolor=\"#d0d0d0\" >";
            else 
                Echo "<tr bgcolor=\"#eeeeee\">";
        $fields = count($twoDimArray[$i]);
        $y = 0;
        echo '<td>'.$i. '</td>';
        foreach ($rowValue as  $fieldName => $fieldValue)
        {
            echo '<td>'.$fieldValue. '</td>';
            $y = $y + 1;
        }
        echo '</tr>';
        $i = $i + 1;
    }


    echo '</table>';
    }


    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Finding live hosts**

The *best* way to be sure you get all live hosts is with a `ping` sweep of the subnet, using a tool like [`nmap`](http://nmap.org/).  Since Windows hosts don't respond to pings by default, it also includes a brief TCP port scan as well.  The syntax from the linux CLI is `nmap -sP 192.0.2.0/24` (substitute your subnet instead of 192.0.2.0/24).

**SNMP query**

I don't think SNMP will really solve your problem, but I will include what I can to assist... When you use the [PHP SNMP Extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.snmp.php), you first need to know the OID for the table with the correct information.  The [LANCOM-1711-MIB](http://www.oidview.com/mibs/2356/LANCOM-1711-MIB.html) is one possibility, but it's hard to know for sure; you should contact LANCOM support if you don't know which SNMP OID to poll.

Let's just go on the assumption that `staDhcpLanIpadd` (OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.2356.500.2.1712.1.32.21.1.2) is the OID you need.  At this point, you would `snmpwalk` the router using SNMPv2c and the SNMP community you configured on it.  Presumably, this OID gives you the list of DHCP addresses issued; however, that doesn't mean they are live at the time you poll the router (someone could have unplugged the cable, or turned them off).

Comment: Thank you Mike. Your very clear and well-structured explanations are highly appreciated. I have looked at the MIB and I am still scratching my head though. It would be a lucky strike for me if somebody would have a pre-configured code snippet allowing to pull the BOOTP table from the Lancom router...